# How to differentiate download link function if the value in the database is null?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have succeed to do download link in my system. But, I cannot figure out how to different it if there is null value in the database. Please help me on how to differentiate or give me some idea.

Here is what my coding:

```
  <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download Here" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>'></asp:LinkButton> </td>
```

Comment: You should do some research before asking, this won't be so hard to achieve. And please clarify your question: is "it" a download link? what data are you checking (in the database)? what do you need the LinkButton to do when the data is null?

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to hide the link if the ID is null, then you can do something like this

```
  <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download Here" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>' Visible='<%# not IsDBNull(Eval("id")) %>'></asp:LinkButton></td>
```